Why does setting Visual Studio 2022's alpha value with SetLayeredWindowAttributes return false?
public static int SetAlpha(IntPtr hwnd, byte alpha)
{
    int exStyle = (int)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    int previousExStyle = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_LAYERED);

    if (previousExStyle == 0 && GetLastError() != 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, alpha, LWA_ALPHA) ? 0 : -1;
}

When I pass in the Visual Studio form handle, it returns false.
I've noticed that for some Unity games or software that have anti-cheat, SetLayeredWindowAttributes doesn't successfully set the alpaca value either.
Does VS2022 have a similar mechanism?

When SetLayeredWindowAttributes fails it sets the last error code. Make sure you thoroughly read the documentation on the requirements for the hwnd parameter. That said, attempting to modify a window you do not own is generally unreliable.
